# Detecting a Wacom Intuos tablet in a Swift macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, events, tablet

I'm using Swift 5.7 to build a macOS app that I want to control with an Wacom Intuos Pro tablet.

On my Mac Studio running on macOS 13.0 Ventura, Wacom's ScribbleDemo project (built on Objective-C) builds and runs fine, and their app successfully detects the tablet (and outputs a log message "I see 1 tablets attached"), and captures all of the tablet pen's event stream (e.g. Pressure, Tilt X, Tilt Y, Abs X, Abs Y) in their app. Here is the ScribbleDemo project on GitHub:
https://github.com/Wacom-Developer/wacom-device-kit-macos-scribble-demo/tree/master/ScribbleDemo

I've added the Wacom driver files from Wacom project to my project, and linked to them using an Objective-C bridging header which declares the names files as follows:

```
    #import "NSAppleEventDescriptorHelperCategory.h"
    #import "TabletAEDictionary.h"
    #import "TabletEvents.h"
    #import "Wacom.h"
    #import "WacomTabletDriver.h"
```

I've tried replicating the top level of their application including the tablet detection function call (WacomTabletDriver.tabletCount()), however it comes back with "I see 0 tablets attached".

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    import Cocoa

    @main
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
        func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
            // Insert code here to initialize your application
            self.tabletInfo()
        }
        func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
            // Insert code here to tear down your application
        }
        func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
        func tabletInfo() {
            let numTablets = WacomTabletDriver.tabletCount()
            print("I see \(numTablets) tablets attached")
        }
    }
```

I've confirmed that my project is able to call functions in the WacomTabletDriver class.

Similar to the Wacom project, I've tried adding the following function sendEvent to the main application class, however it doesn't seem to get called:

```
    func sendEvent(with event: NSEvent) {
        print("sendEvent called!")
    }
```

I've also tried subclassing NSApplication, and making it shared with the subclass of NSApplicationDelegate, however the sendEvent function also doesn't print a message to the console (nor does the message get printed about the number of tablets attached):

```
    import Cocoa

    class MyApplication: NSApplication {
        override init() {
            super.init()
            let numTablets = WacomTabletDriver.tabletCount()
            print("I see \(numTablets) tablets attached")
        }
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: coder)
        }
        override func sendEvent(_ event: NSEvent) {
            print("sendEvent is called!")
            super.sendEvent(event) // Call the superclass method to handle the event
        }
    }

    @NSApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
        func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
            // Insert code here to initialize your application
            let application = MyApplication.shared
        }
        func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
            // Insert code here to tear down your application
        }
    }
```

I believe the problem relates to the structure of the app (NSApplication and/or NSApplication) however I haven't been able to sort this out from other posts here, and other documentation only. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

---

UPDATE: With the comments from @apodidae and @NSGod I was able to detect the Wacom tablet.

Regarding the related issue of sending (and receiving) the tablet data via NSEvent, I received a helpful tip today from Wacom Support. They suggested using these entitlements:

```
<key>com.apple.security.automation.apple-events</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events</key>
<array>
    <string>com.wacom.TabletDriver</string>
</array>
```

Now, I am able to access the tablet event data by adding the same Wacom driver files, the same list of files in the Objective-C bridging header, and following code to the NSViewController:

```
func handleMouseEvent(with event: NSEvent) {

    if (event.isTabletPointerEvent()) {
        let eventType = Int(event.type.rawValue)
        var mPressure: Float = 0.0
      
        if eventType != NSEvent.EventType.mouseMoved.rawValue {
            mPressure = event.pressure;
        } else {
            mPressure = 0.0
        }
      
        let loc = event.locationInWindow
        let mMouseX = loc.x
        let mMouseY = loc.y
        let mTabletScaledPressure = event.pressure
        let mAbsX = Int32(event.absoluteX)
        let mAbsY = Int32(event.absoluteY)
        let tilt = event.tilt
        let mTiltX = tilt.x
        let mTiltY = tilt.y
        let mRotDeg = event.rotation
        let mRotRad = event.rotationInRadians()
      
        print("x:", mMouseX, "y:", mMouseY, "xAbs:", mAbsX, "yAbs:", mAbsY,
            "p:", mPressure, "pScaled:", mTabletScaledPressure,
            "tX:", mTiltX, "tY:", mTiltY, "mRotDeg:", mRotDeg, "mRotRad", mRotRad)
    }
}

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    handleMouseEvent(with: event)
}

override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
    handleMouseEvent(with: event)
}

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    handleMouseEvent(with: event)
}
```

Comment: `func sendEvent(with event: NSEvent)` isn't called because it should be `override func sendEvent(_ event: NSEvent)`. `let application = MyApplication.shared` doesn't work `application` is deallocated at the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: Is this a sandbox issue? Are the Signing & Capabilities settings the same as the demo project?

Comment: It appears communication to the Wacom driver is done using Apple Events, so maybe make sure you have a "send apple events" entitlement enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If you want WacomTabletDriver.tabletCount() to return 1 instead of 0 add 'Privacy - AppleEvents Sending Usage Description' to the info.plist.  Set Sandbox to NO and set Apple Events to YES in xxx.entitlements.  Add the following two lines to the +tabletCount method of WacomTabletDriver.m and you will see why it works.

```
reply = [event sendExpectingReplyWithPriority:kAEHighPriority andTimeout:kTabletDriverAETimeout];
    NSLog(@"%@",reply);
    NSLog(@"%@",[reply descriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject]);
```

Without adding the extra line to info.plist this returns null.  After adding the extra line it has the correct value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @apodidae. This worked just as you described, and probably saved me several days of trying to sort this out. For completeness, here is the key that I added to xxx.entitlements: `<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key><false/>`